# i have mAdView.loadAd(adRequest); error

Tags: java, android, admob

I have been try to Add Admob into my app but i always got:

```
at com.blogspot.tholutech.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:31)   
mAdView.loadAd(adRequest);
```

[image]

Comment: Hi, welcome to stack overflow. Please refer the [ask] link for 
more details on how to ask a question and update your question accordingly.

Comment: show image and code format

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no `adView` in your layout yet. You have to call `setContentView()` before you try to access your views.